# Thunderstorm sound when joining server followed by fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Recently upon joining my Tekkit Lite server I've been hearing these large rumbling sounds like you'd get during a thunderstorm, however when I actually spawn in the world it's a nice calm day with no rain or lightning in sight.

Additionally I noticed it had also caused the outbreak of a number of fires which is quite annoying as it sets a number of trees on fire which then quickly spreads across the entire forested region that I'm situated by.

What could be causing these mysterious thunderstorm sounds and fires? - It would be nice to get to the bottom as this has happened twice now.

*Another note: This problem has also been experienced by other players on the server however I myself have yet to actually play in a thunderstorm. Also another point is that this doesn't seem to occur every time I join, just a few.*

Thanks!

Comment: Couple questions to help diagnose the problem: Does this happen to the others on the server as well? Or do they see a thunderstorm? Have you ever seen an actual thunderstorm on this particular server?

Comment: Good question! Yes others have also experienced this on the server as  well as the thunderstorm however I can't recall ever actually being in one.

Comment: Does tekkit lite have Thaumcraft? If so, this may be a freak occurence with a dark node playing up. Also, the plugin VanishNoPacket (I think it's this one) has an option that shoots you with lightning and bats whenever you reappear.

Comment: Can you record a video to demonstrate this effect?

Comment: Late side note (might be obvious): The thunderstorm sounds with no actual thunderstorms, combined with fires, seem to indicate that groups of lightnings are spawned. If investigation is still ongoing, that might point someone in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

What it could be is the server using that as a sort of "hello" sort of thing. Seeing as how whenever you join the server, and the other players see that  this happen as well. I can only assume that the server owner or admin intends for this to happen and is using a part of the mod pack or is using a plugin from Bukkit or another mod to make this happen.

It also could be a coincidental bug, but that happening exactly the same time with the other people is pretty unlikely.

Comment: Sorry, was probably worth mentioning that this is actually my server and currently I don't have any plugins that would be doing this. Simply an economy mod and that's about it.